# boost single thread libraries in cygwin

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin, boost-date-time

I just built and installed boost_1_47_0 using the following on cygwin

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=chrono,date_time,exception,filesystem,graph,graph_parallel,iostreams,math,program_options,random,serialization,signals,system,test,thread,wave  link=static link=shared threading=single threading=multi
```

then I ran the below,

```
./b2  --layout=tagged
```

and the message indicated that it:

```
failed updating 2 targets and skipped 7 targets....
```

but I continued and ran

```
./b2  --layout=tagged install
```

however, I look in /usr/local/lib and I only have those libraries with suffix -mt

My programs are looking for the libraries without the -mt suffix. 
but since it didn't work, I ran in sequence:

```
bjam --clean debug release

./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=all

./b2

./b2 --layout=tagged

./b2 --layout=tagged install
```

but I still see only the -mt libraries in /usr/local/lib

can anyone please suggest how this can be fixed (my programs look for libboost_date_time and not libboost_date_time-mt)...thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "--layout=system"

Comment: I just ran ./b2 --layout=system. After that completed, I am now running ./b2 --layout=system install. I shall post as soon as it completed. and it worked....thanks so much :-)